# Python Function runs to first if statement no matter input

Tags: python

I'm learning Python from an online tutorial. My problem is that when I run the script, no matter what I input the response I get is the if go == "kitchen"...

```
def go_to():
    go = raw_input("Go to? ")

    if go == Kitchen or breakfast:
         print "You rumble down stairs and into the kitchen. Your mom has left some microwaved waffles on the table for you. Your big boy step sits by the counter."
    elif go == "back to bed" or "back to sleep" or bed or sleep:
        print "You hit snooze and roll over."
    elif go == "bathroom" or "toilet" or "potty" or "pee" or "poop" or "take a sh*t" or "take a dump" or "drop a load":
        print "You make a stop at the head first."
        go_to()
    else:
        print "That is not a command I understand."
        go_to()
go_to()
```

Comment: You need a new tutorial, since that usage of `or` is incorrect.

Comment: As it stands, this program will abort with a Syntax error. Indentation is significant in Python. Please fix that. Also, you have things like `bed` and `sleep` which are unquoted. That will error out too when your function is called.

Comment: You don't like `"` and `'` chars, do you?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question in its own terms. It's not OP's fault that he has a terrible tutorial. This should be left open.

Comment: Also, don't mix spaces and tabs for indentation.

Comment: @Marcin: I voted to close as too localized, but I could dig out at least 10 duplicates as well.

Comment: why did someone downvote? it's a valid question, no matter how simple. unless because of duplicates.

Comment: @Wooble then post the duplicates. If there are duplicates, then by definition this isn't localized.

Comment: @user1571810, This is [*a good python tutorial*](http://diveintopython.net/): please use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ignacio says, you need a new tutorial.

The expression `go == Kitchen or breakfast` will be true if either of the subexpressions `go == Kitchen` or `breakfast` evaluate to `True`. This will happen if `go` evaluates to the same object as `Kitchen`, or their type defines an `__eq__` method which defines equality for them, or it will be the case if `breakfast` is an object that is not `None`.

The way to check if a variable contains a value in a list is:

```
if go in (Kitchen, breakfast):
   # do something
```

Note also that your code doesn't show where the variables `Kitchen` and `breakfast` are defined, and your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: yeah, they werent meant to be variables, but strings. i was just trying different things and took the quotes off and forgot to put them back on. thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1571810 It doesn't matter whether they are variables or strings. The same evaluation rules apply (except of course that there is an extra step of evaluation).

Answer (score 5):

As was mentioned in the comments, your use of `or` is incorrect here. This:

```
go == "kitchen" or "breakfast"
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(go == "kitchen") or "breakfast"
```

The `or` operator casts both of its operands to booleans, which gives you:

```
(something) or true
```

That always reduces to `true`, so you always enter the if statement

Answer (score 0):

i beleive the problem is with your first if statement

in most programming languages you can't just say "or" like you do. what you need to do is repeat the "go ==" part for all conditions.

```
if go == Kitchen or go == breakfast:
```

what it is doing right now is evaluating (go == Kitchen) and finding it false.  then it is evaluating "breakfast" and that returns true.  since it is an "or" statement then the entire if is true.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
if go == "Kitchen" or "breakfast":
```

is wrong because of the order of evaluation. It seems you intend to check if go is either "kitchen" or "breakfast". However, you check if go is "kitchen" or the string "breakfast" is true. The latter is always the case, because a non-empty string evaluates to something that is not False.

The intuitive way of describing your intent would be:

```
if (go == "kitchen") or (go == "breakfast"):
```

Probably more pythonic you could also write:

```
if go in ["kitchen", "breakfast"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a condition is one of a list of things, then you should use `in`, eg:

```
if go in ('Bathroom', 'take a dump', 'have a beep'):
    # do something...
elif go in ('Kitchen', 'Living room'):
    # etc...
else:
    # no idea where to go?
```

The use of `or` doesn't do what you expect and has been explained in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

What your code says is that if go in kitchen or breakfast So for python it means
if go in kitchen or if breakfast

so, it's either Something or True.
it resolves to the True and thus the first if statement always gets executed.
You can fix it by
`if go in ['kitchen', 'breakfast']`