# What is wrong with the ordering of this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a Pig Latin translator in Python.  I don't have the finished product yet and I'm working through Codecademy.  Here is my code so far:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original
    if first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print 'empty'
word = original.lower()
first = word [0]
```

I'm pretty sure the last two lines are out of place, but I do not know where they should go and I don't know why.  If anybody could explain that to me, that would be great.  I'm just at the stage of this program where I want to check if the first letter is a vowel or consonant, I'm not at the translating part yet.

Comment: What's `first`?  Where is it defined?

Comment: It's defined on the last line.  I know this is wrong, but I don't know where it should go.

Answer (score 5):

You're defining `word` and `first` after you check their values, so try moving those after you define `original` and after you check the length (to avoid an index error on empty values).

Also, where you use `if len(original) > 0`, you actually simplify that to `if original`, which  will return `True` if it is a non-null value.

One other thing - your check for vowels will not return the expected value. Instead, try something like this:

```
if first in 'aeiou':
```

I'm sure there are better ways to handle it, but this should work for your case.

**EDIT:**
Changing the `if` statement to @Levon's method (which is much more Pythonic)

Comment: What does the in mean?  I have never seen that in Python before.

Comment: In this context, it's a way of saying "check if `first` is any one of these" and is what you were trying to accomplish with the `or` statements. @Levon used a simpler (and better) form than I did, but they both do the same thing - iterate through something (in @Levon's case, a string; in mine, a tuple) and compare `first` to each value. If one of them matches, it executes the code in the `if` block.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
```

Does not behave the way you expect. [I actually answered basically this exact question a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11781035/1084754).

Let me know if you don't understand the explanation I gave there.

Answer (score 3):

**(1)** Your `if`-statement could be rewritten in a shortened (and correct) version like this:

```
if first in 'aeiou':
```

I answered this with more explanation recently [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809145/1209279) for someone else working on the same problem as you.

**(2)** Re your question about where to place these two lines of code:

```
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]
```

Put them after your `print original` inside your `if`-statement. They convert your input word to lowercase, and then take the first letter of the word and assign it to the variable `first` which is then subsequently used to check for vowel/consonant.